# How to add font awesome to custom word press snippet

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

I am trying to add a font awesome image to my custom snippet in WordPress.

I want to add a money bag in front of my WP job manager salary snippet.

Font awesome image ref below;

```html
<i class="far fa-money-bill-alt"></i>
```

The custom code can be seen below;

```php
add_action( 'single_job_listing_meta_end', 'display_job_salary_data' );

function display_job_salary_data() {
  global $post;

  $salary = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_job_salary', true );

  if ( $salary ) {
    echo '<li>' . __( 'Salary:' ) . ' $' . esc_html( $salary ) . '</li>';
  }
}
```

I have included a photo below of the current page;

[image]

Hopefully someone out there can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your markup like that:

```php
echo '<li><i class="far fa-money-bill-alt"></i>' . __( 'Salary:' ) . ' $' . esc_html( $salary ) . '</li>';
```

Alternatively, you could target this `li` and add your icon using the `::before` pseudo-element.

```php
echo '<li id="salary">' . __( 'Salary:' ) . ' $' . esc_html( $salary ) . '</li>';
```

```css
#salary::before {
  content: '\f3d1'; /* the fa-money-bill-alt icon */
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
}
```

If you want to know how to load Font Awesome, check [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) and [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).